# Reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 with online update and Internet is not coming wireless or wired

Tags: internet, ubuntu-drivers, reinstall

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 with Online update but I don't see any Internet neither with Wire nor with wireless. I have b43 Broad come device but since wired net is not there I am not able to bring back Internet. 
Please help.

Comment: When I connect wire I can see the network icon but there is no Internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this by

1. Right click on net icon and removed ipv4 settings.
2. sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer